# How to let Gmail access storage?

Tags: gmail, storage, permissions

When I try to "Share" using Gmail the file never gets attached and I always get the same error: "Gmail needs storage permission to complete action".

[image: error message]

However it then directs me to Gmail settings and under Permissions there is no such option. There is no way to allow Storage Permissions here or under Settings > App Permissions

[image: Gmail settings]

How on earth do I give Gmail the permission it is saying it needs?

Comment: What Android version is running on your phone? Do you use the recent Gmail version from Google Play?

Comment: Based on the permission list, looks like this is on [Android 13 or above](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)? However, I just tried sharing an image, audio, and video from the WhatsApp folder in the internal storage to Gmail on my Galaxy M12 (Android 13), and I successfully attached them without any external storage-related permissions allowed. In case it's relevant, could you also mention the file type and the location (e.g. internal storage or SD card)?

Comment: Very strange issue, can you confirm if apps in Play Store as well as the OS version is up to date? What phone model is this?

Comment: @Robert - this is the latest version of Gmail on Android 13.

Comment: @AndrewT. This is on Android 13. It's internal storage on a brand new from Samsung website Galaxy S23+. It only has internal storage.

Comment: @SSS everything updated to latest versions. New Android 13 Samsung Galaxy S23+ model SM-S916B/DS.

Comment: @AndrewT. In case it's relevant the file is being shared from App storage. It might be due to newer Android locking down app storage in `/Android`? However, sharing from the aoo by other methods works fine.